# Chat window with speech bubble - html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am implementing a page that periodically refreshes fetching random opinions-messages from database and displays it in the chat bubbles, with the user's photos and the date. I want the chat bubbles should scroll up as new messages adds up in the bottom. I got few good chat-bubble css from the many internet pages. I do not know how do I implement the scroll that will eliminate the old chat-bubble (a 'div') on the top (older one) and add the new ones in the bottom? only one random message is fetch on every ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to add scrolls to see your previous messages.